# Using .Value in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I noticed something, when i use INTEGER type Output parameter in sql and access it asp.net code then we don't use .Value with parameter name but when we access Varchar type output parameter then we must put .Value with it in asp.net , why ?

e..g accessing varchar output parameter from sql:

```
SqlParameter pComplaint_ID = new SqlParameter("@Complaint_ID", Complaint_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pComplaint_ID);
            SqlParameter pComplaintName = new SqlParameter("@ComplaintName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pComplaintName);
            pComplaintName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string Result = Convert.ToString(pComplaintName.Value);
            return Result;
```

see 2nd last line but when i use Integer e.g. pCmp_ID then no need to put .Value, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the parameter by the `command` object, for sample:

```
SqlParameter pComplaint_ID = new SqlParameter("@Complaint_ID", Complaint_ID);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pComplaint_ID);

SqlParameter pComplaintName = new SqlParameter("@ComplaintName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
pComplaintName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pComplaintName);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string Result = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@ComplaintName"].Value);
return Result;
```

Comment: The way you need to read the parameter, `cmd.Parameters["@ComplaintName"].Value`.